# C# referenced component 'UiaComWrapper' not found

Tags: c#, nuget-package

When I tried to rebuild solution in my C# project in visual studio, following reference component warning came:
The referenced component 'UiaComWrapper' could not be found.    Testing

Comment: That sounds as if you found that warning was not deserved, can you show how?

Comment: Hi Stefan! Thank you for your response; however, it got sorted as I removed those references.